# What is an example of lower semicontinuous functions not satisfying this?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $\mu$ be a Radon measure on $X$.

Let $u:X\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be a lower semicontinuous function such that $\int_X u d\mu <\infty$.

Then, does there exist a lower semicontinuous function $U:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $U=u, \mu$-a.e.?

Comment: Is it true that $\{x \in X : u(x) = \infty\}$ is closed?

Comment: @GEdgar No, not necessarily.

Comment: I suspect something like $X = [0,1]$, $u(x) = \sum_k 2^{-k} {1 \over \sqrt{|x-q_k|}}$ where $\{q_k\}$ is a countable dense subset would work, but I'm not sure/haven't been able to work out the details.

Comment: Let me clarify: the above $u$ is integrable by the monotone convergence theorem, and it is lsc since it is an increasing limit of lsc functions. On the other hand, this function is unbounded on any interval. Since we must set $U(q_k)$ to be finite for every $q_k$, it follows that the set $\{q_k:U(q_k) \leq \alpha\}$ must be nowhere dense for every $\alpha > 0$. Thus, by density and lower semicontinuity, the set $\{q_k : U(q_k) > \alpha\}$ must be dense for every $\alpha$. On the other hand, the set $\{x : U(x) \leq \alpha\}$ has big measure for $\alpha$ big, by integrability.

Comment: However, this doesn't quite finish the job, as there are sets of big measure which don't have any, e.g., rational limit points.